What is a 'fact' for early Wittgenstein?
In a nutshell: what is meant by a 'fact' in Tractatus Logico-Philosophicus?

At the beginning of the text, it seems clear to me what Wittgenstein means by a 'fact', namely, a (real) state of affairs, a true proposition:




The world is everything that is the case.


1.1. The world is the totality of facts, not of things.
1.11. The world is determined by the facts, and by these being all the facts.
1.12.  For the totality of facts determines both what is the case, and also all that is not the case.
1.13. The facts in logical space are the world.
1.2. The world divides into facts.


However, further down the text we have the following points (bold added by me):


2.1. We make to ourselves pictures of facts.
2.14. What constitutes a picture is that its elements are related to one another in a determinate way.
2.141. A picture is a fact.


The logical picture of the facts is the thought.


3.14. What constitutes a propositional sign is that in it its elements (the words) stand in a determinate relation to one another. A propositional sign is a fact.


My understanding is that a picture is some sort of mental image, a subset of these mental images may be called thoughts. On the other hand, a propositional sign is a written, spoken, or otherwise represented proposition. If this is correct, how can a picture or a propositional sign be a fact?
Moreover, if a fact is an actual state of affairs, wouldn't 'false' mental pictures (e.g. me imagining my wallet currently has $50, when it is in fact empty) not be facts? A similar question arises for 'false' propositional signs.

See Facts: "Facts, philosophers like to say, are opposed to theories and to values and are to be distinguished from things, in particular from complex objects, complexes and wholes, and from relations. They are the objects of certain mental states and acts, they make truth-bearers true and correspond to truths, they are part of the furniture of the world. "

The clauses "Facts are to be distinguished from things [...] they are part of the furniture of the world" apply to W, because they are the furniture of the world.

A "picture" is a written/spoken sentence, and thus is itself part of reality. It corersponds to another fact by way of a "common structure": the logical form.

A good question. Propositions by themselves are state of affairs too. They are relations of objects. However they can be isomorphic to other state of affairs, where the objects themselves are then different but the structure is the same.

Welcome! I'm not going to downvote, but this claim "Propositions by themselves are state of affairs too" seems to go against the conventional definition of state of affairs: "a state of affairs (German: Sachverhalt),[1] also known as a situation, is a way the actual world must be in order to make some given proposition about the actual world true; in other words, a state of affairs is a truth-maker, whereas a proposition is a truth-bearer". How do you reconcile you claim against this definition?

Yes but they are fact by themselves also. If you draw a picture that is too something physical by itself, even if it represents something else.

Some propositions are true fact and some are false fact, and some are a matter of opinion. The claim you make about the picture can be resolved by recognizing there is a difference in medium and message. In fact, McCluhan recognized sometimes the medium is the message. The medium of the picture is physical, but the message is not. In linguistics and philosophy, we recognize, generally recognize a distinction between utterance or statement and proposition. The utterance is the concrete realization (either as physical medium...

relative to the conceptual content or syntax relative to the semantic import) and the proposition is the actual idea that is communicated (or at least intended to be communicated).
